# Multistore force www to on-www per store

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

For a multistore PrestaShop I have, let's say: example.com [main domain] and example.org [extra store].

It's all setup nicely, without www, but when I visit www.example.org, it brings me to example.com.

I would say this helps:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Or just for all the domains, I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that also doesn't work. I put all of this before the `# ~~start~~ Do not remove this`-line.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to add a `.htaccess` file on the your other domains too. So for `example.com` you will need to have a `.htaccess` file that is forcing `www`.

Comment: It has a symbolic link to the main account. So hosting accounts are ignored entirely. There is one htacces file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from the PrestaShop forum. I can't put links here. I will explain both `www` to `non-www` en `non-www` to `www`:

### 1. www to non-www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

### 2. non-www to www

I haven't tried this because this is not setup in my PrestaShop installation.  I've seen that people refer to this code many times, so it must work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't know why *Knowband Plugin*'s code doesn't work. If someone could clarify that, it would be of great educational value.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code to the .htaccess file in root directory of PrestaShop installation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I like the code, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. This makes me think of something. Maybe the problem lies in the symbolic link in CentOs. The accounts in DirectAdmin might redirect to the non-www main domain.